# Heroku server State changed from up to crashed

Tags: node.js, heroku, discord, discord.js

I tried every solution possible but I keep getting this error in Heroku
I got it with heroku logs, but it's not a great explanation

```
2022-02-22T00:35:48.218009+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2022-02-22T00:35:50.921052+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2022-02-22T00:35:51.589791+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2022-02-22T00:35:52.062215+00:00 app[worker.1]:
2022-02-22T00:35:52.062230+00:00 app[worker.1]: > start
2022-02-22T00:35:52.062230+00:00 app[worker.1]: > node index.js
2022-02-22T00:35:52.062230+00:00 app[worker.1]:
2022-02-22T00:35:52.244828+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 0
2022-02-22T00:35:52.354881+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
```

I have Node.js 17.5.0 (latest) and Npm 8.4.1

I have my project updated to Heroku and proceeded as explained in the "deploy" part in Heroku's website.

I also have my Procfile with this:

```
worker: npm start
```

Having web npm start off and worker npm start on in Heroku's website.

The bot is basically a discord music bot, but until now, except if I execute the code manually, I couldn't make it work by using Heroku.

Comment: What's in your `index.js`? "Exited with status 0" usually indicates that the script just finished, successfully/

Comment: Thank you!! The problem was that my discord bot was in a file which I created called Bot.js and I had to put it in index.js, thak you very much!!!

Answer (score 1):

In your `package.json` did you add:

```
"engines": {
  "node": "16.x"
}
```